# Why are tasks in Microsoft Project turned red?

Tags: microsoft-project

I noticed that tasks in my MS Project in Gantt view turned red, out of my control. Can you help to explain what might happen?

Answer (score 4):

As already said, they entered your project's critical path.

Given you have set a deadline for your project and it is already late, "red" in a task means that if it's finish date increases (because of more work, less resources or late start), the finish date for the *whole project* increases in the same proportion - and so project lateness.

Answer (score 3):

It's becuase they are on the critical path of your project.

Check out articles on Earned Value, Future Value etc to see how it calculates it

-Ben